# Seleccionar por defecto el mes y año actual en Select

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Estoy tratando de hacer un `select` pero que este seleccionado por defecto el `mes` actual con un `ng-init` lo mismo para el `año`, pero no logro conseguirlo, tengo el siguiente `código`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.years = [];
    $scope.year = null;
    $scope.months = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
    $scope.month = null;

    $scope.initYears = function () {
        $scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $scope.years.push($scope.year-i);
            console.log($scope.year-i);
        }        
    }
    
    $scope.initMonth = function() {
        var date = new Date();
        $scope.month = $scope.months[date.getMonth()];
        console.log($scope.month);
    }  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Code Sample</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <label class="control-label">Mes</label>
            <select ng-model="month" ng-init="initMonth()" class="form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="month in months" ng-value="month" ng-bind="month"></option>
            </select>
            <label class="control-label">Año</label>
            <select ng-model="year" ng-init="initYears()" class="form-control">
                <option ng-repeat="year in years" ng-value="year" ng-bind="year"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: con definir el valor inicial en el `$scope.month` en vez de `null` el `ng-model` tendría que levantarlo, tal vez cambiarle el nombre a `$scope.currentMonth` en el `ng-model` y `ng-bind` para que no choque con el `month` del `ng-value`

Comment: @aloMalbarez con ng-selected se puede lograr? y si cambiar los nombres tiene razón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sería mejor que por defecto month tenga el valor del mes actual a realizarlo con una función? De esta forma:

```
$scope.month = $scope.months[new Date().getMonth()];
```

Lo mismo para el año =)

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Code Sample</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <label class="control-label">Mes</label>
            <select ng-model="month" class="form-control" ng-options="m for m in months"></select>
            
            <label class="control-label">Año</label>
            <select ng-model="year" class="form-control" ng-options="y for y in years"></select>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.years = [];
        $scope.year = new Date().getFullYear();
        $scope.months = ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"]
        $scope.month = $scope.months[new Date().getMonth()];
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $scope.years.push($scope.year-i);
            //console.log($scope.year-i);
        }  
    })
    </script>
</html>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo; también edite un poco los `select` y utilice `ng-options` en desmedro de *option*.

Nos comentas

Comment: me puedes explicar por que mejor el ng-options y como se usa, por que el for?

Comment: `ng-options` es la implementación por defecto de un `select` si utilizas **AngularJS**; por lo que entiendo, no existe una diferencia sustancial entre usar `ng-options` y `option` nativo de **HTML**, puedes usar el que te acomode. En cuanto al `for` es la palabra que indica que el alias (_m en caso de month_) hace referencia a cada objeto del array que contiene las opciones que quieres desplegar, no se si me expliqué. Te dejo el link para que conozcas la implementación más al detalle https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: ok listo muchas gracias, perfecto.